# What is the contrapositive of "if $x^2 (y + 3)$ is even, then $x$ is even or $y$ is odd"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I believe the contrapositive of this would be:

If $x$ is odd, or $y$ is even, then $x^2 (y + 3)$ is odd.

Or would it be:

If $x$ is odd, AND $y$ is even, then $x^2 (y + 3)$ is odd.

Is one of these correct?

Answer (score 1):

> If $x^2(y + 3)$ is even, then $x$ is even or $y$ is odd.

This is an implication of the form $P \implies Q$, with

$P$: $x^2(y + 3)$ is even

$Q$: $x$ is even or $y$ is odd

The contrapositive is $\neg Q \implies \neg P$.  You correctly determined that $\neg P$ is

> $x^2(y + 3)$ is odd

One of [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) states that the negation of the statement $A$ OR $B$ is (NOT $A$) AND (NOT $B$).  In symbols, $\neg(A \vee B) = (\neg A) \wedge (\neg B)$.

Therefore, $\neg Q$ is

> $x$ is odd and $y$ is even

Hence, the contrapositive of the given statement is

> If $x$ is odd and $y$ is even, then $x^2(y + 3)$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

The contrapositive of "If P then Q" is "If not Q then not P.

In your statement
$$P: x^2(y+3) \mbox { is even }\\
Q: x \mbox{ is even or } y \mbox{ is odd }$$

What are not $Q$ and not $P$?

Comment: Ah, I didn't reverse the implication order or P and Q.  However, I know what not P is, but I'm unsure of what not Q is.  Is not Q "x is odd OR y is even" or is it "x is odd AND y is even"?

Comment: $Q$ is of the form ($A$ or $B$). By De Morgan's law, the negation of this, not ($A$ or $B$), is equivalent to (not $A$ and not $B$). So not $Q$ is "x is odd AND y is even". [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) is a fundamental pattern of mathematical (and other) reasoning, used all the time and generally without comment. Actually, it's laws plural: there are two, each obtained from the other by interchanging "and" and "or".

Comment: The original implication was "If $x^2(y + 3)$ is even, then $x$ is even or $y$ is odd."  Hence, $P$ should be $x^2(y + 3)$ is even.